# printf not displaying correctly in bash

Tags: bash, macos, printf

I have printf statements that are not displaying correctly in a Terminal window.
The first two display correctly but the third `printf "Writing to %s$output%s" "$biwhite" "$color_off"` is not showing up except for the last few characters of `$output`

It feels like a bug of some sort. If I substitute `echo` for `printf` the line displays correctly, minus the coloring.
 I've tried putting all the statements in one `printf` with the same results. It is as though `printf` reallllly hates that one sentence. I'm at a loss as to what could be causing it. I'm working in OSX.

```
biwhite=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 7)
#bired=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 1)
color_off=$(tput sgr0)
date="$(date +%Y%m%d)"


while [[ $# -gt 0 ]] ; do

input="$1" #name $input as the first arugment sent to script

if [ -d "$input" ] ; then   #if argment is a directory, run md5deep
  target="${input%/}" #strip the trailing /, if any
  target="${target##*/}" #drop the leading directory componenets i.e. get basename
  output="$input"/"$target"_"$date"_checksums.md5 #set .md5 file to $output
  printf "%s${input##*/}%s is a directory.\n" "$biwhite" "$color_off"
  printf "Making checksums of all files in %s$input%s\n" "$biwhite" "$color_off"
  printf "Writing to %s$output%s" "$biwhite" "$color_off"
  md5deep -bre "$input" >> "$output" #create md5 hash (hashes) of $input and write results to $output
fi
shift

done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, the format string argument to printf should be constant. Thus:

```
printf '%s%s%s is a directory.\n' "$biwhite" "${input##*/}" "$color_off" # GOOD
printf 'Writing to %s%s%s\n' "$biwhite" "$output" "$color_off"           # GOOD
```

...or...

```
printf '%s is a directory.\n' "$biwhite${input##*/}$color_off"           # GOOD
printf 'Writing to %s\n' "$biwhite$output$color_off"                     # GOOD
```

As opposed to:

```
printf "%s${input##*/}%s is a directory.\n" "$biwhite" "$color_off"      # BAD
printf "Writing to %s$output%s\n" "$biwhite" "$color_off"                # BAD
```

---

Otherwise, behavior can be hard to predict:

- Any `%` signs inside your `"$output"` can throw off how other positional arguments are interpreted.
- Any backslash-escape sequences will be substituted with referenced characters -- a literal tab for `\t`, a carriage-return for `\r`, etc. (If you *want* this, use `%b` instead of `%s` in the specific positions where you want such substitutions to take place).

Comment: Ahhh I see... `$output` is a file path that I want to be colorized when displayed so I thought I would need to bookend it with `$biwhite` and `$color_off`

Comment: Sure -- but by putting a `%s` placeholder for all three of `"$biwhite"`, `"$output"` and `"$color_off"`, or having only one placeholder and passing the full concatenated string for it, you can have that same effect without having the contents of `output` parsed as a format string itself.